# Elements in an array occurring more than size/2

Tags: c++, arrays

I need help in one of the small arrays related question.

> Given an array A of N elements. Find the majority element in the array. A majority element in an array A of size N is an element that appears more than N/2 times in the array.
>
> EXAMPLE 1:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> N = 3
> A[] = {1,2,3}
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> -1
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> Since, each element in {1,2,3} appears only once so there is no majority element.
>
> EXAMPLE 2:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> N = 5
> A[] = {3,1,3,3,2}
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> Since, 3 is present more than N/2 times, so it is the majority element.

My code:

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    int cn=1;
    for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++) {
        if(a[i]==a[j]) {
            cn++;
            if(cn>size/2) {
                return a[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```

The above code takes two iteration.

The first iteration `i=0; i<size; i++` is used to iterate through each element, similarly the second loop `j=i+1; j<size; j++;` is used to compare the element at i'th position with the rest of the element in an array. While comparing the i'th element with the other elements in an arrays, if it's found that number of occurrence of i'th element is greater than the `size/2` then it returns that particular element. If not, then it returns -1.

Although the above code satisfies multiple test cases, there's a single test case which it fails to satisfy.

> Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).
>
> The first test case where your code failed:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 1
> 15
> ```
>
> Its Correct output is:
>
> ```
> 15
> ```
>
> And Your Code's output is:
>
> ```
> -1
> ```

Can anyone tell me the reason behind it? Is my logic incorrect, or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like the problem or the test case is wrong for me. `{1, 15}` is a 2-element array, and "N/2 times" for that is 1 times. 15 appears only 1 times in that, and it is not more than 1 times (N/2 times). Also it doesn't look reasonable that the answer is 15 while 1 appears just the same times as 15.

Comment: Yes your logic is incorrect, you do not handle arrays of size 1, which should have been the second thing to test (the first thing is size 0). Use a debugger to find the flaw. I'm afraid it will not be enough to fix this specific case though, because your algorithm is O(n^2), which is suboptimal. The competition is probably designed to weed out submissions with asymptotically suboptimal algorithms.

Comment: @MikeCAT 1 is probably the size of the array.

Comment: Use `std::map` to calculate the occurrence of each number.  You can then iterate through the `std::map` to do your calculations.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect for another reason: If the first element is not a "majority element" the code simply returns -1, even if there's a majority element. Furthermore using `continue;` as the last statement in a loop body just adds unnecessary noise; the program continues with the next iteration anyways.

Comment: Your code is sub-optimal. You can do it in O(n) using a map but even this approach would take O(n) extra space. Try reading Boyer-Moore's majority element algorithm which can accomplish this same task in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic almost works, despite being suboptimal as mentioned by many in the comment.

The problem here is that your inner for loop will be completely skipped if `size == 1`, which makes it return `-1` when you only have one element in.

Without changing much of your logic, you can simply add a return before your for loop:

```
if(size == 1) return a[0];
```

---

One more thing is that you want to make sure your `return -1` is after the outer for loop.

It might be a bad copy paste, but as current, it will just `return -1` when the first item isn't the majority.

---

More on the optimized solution: [Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm)